# incompatibility between notes2bib and plos15 style?

Tags: bibtex, endnotes

I am writing a paper for PLOS that does not permit footnotes or endnotes aside from the references, so I would like my footnotes to appear in the references section.  PLOS mandates the plos15.bst style.  Unfortunately, I have tried to use \bibnotes in the notes2bib package with this style, but the references just appear as blanks:

`[13] ;.`

and give compilation warnings:

`BibTeX: empty author in Note 1`
`BibTeX: empty title in Note 1`
`BibTeX: there's a month but no year in Note1`

I noticed that with the `unsrt` style, it works fine, and with the `vancouver` style, it sort of works, but prepends each bibnote with `;.`

I tried (without success) setting some options based on my reading of the documentation, for example:

```
\bibnotesetup{
    note-name = ,
    use-sort-key = false
    }
```

I would like to know if there's a way to get `\bibnote` functionality with `plos15`, or with the `vancouver` style.